# Import only table to Postgres in Dokku

Tags: postgresql, docker, dokku

Dokku doesn't work with Postgres commands. How can I import a new table and new data to existing table in Postgres without messing with other tables?

Comment: did you find out?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `dokku postgres:expose $SERVICE_NAME` for the postgres service to expose it on an external port, after which you can connect via your postgres commands to the database in question. Remember to call `dokku postgres:unexpose $SERVICE_NAME` when you are done.